# arm-gcc unresolved reference 'sinf'

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm getting this error when trying to compile:

```
error: undefined reference to `sinf'
```

I have included math.h, and verified that it is defined in there:

```
#include <math.h>
```

However,  I get an error while trying to link to the math library:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -L/usr/lib -lm --gc-sections -T ../standalone.ld -o "main.elf"  ./main.o ./startup_gcc.o  
error: cannot find -lm
```

However, the library is obviously there:

```
Kens-MacBook-Pro:lib Ken$ pwd
/usr/lib
Kens-MacBook-Pro:lib Ken$ ls | grep libm
libm.dylib
libmecab.1.0.0.dylib
libmecab.dylib
libmecabra.dylib
libmenu.5.4.dylib
libmenu.dylib
libmx.A.dylib
libmx.dylib
Kens-MacBook-Pro:lib Ken$
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: @chux OP says the math library isn't being linked. I don't see how using a different function in the same library is going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your `arm-none-eabi-ld` command, I'm assuming you're cross compiling. You need to install some sort of math library into the toolchain for whatever your platform is.

The `ls` output you posted contains a list of libraries available for your host, not your target. On my machine, the libraries for my ARM cross-compiler resides in `/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/lib/` for example.

```
danieltang ~$ ls /opt/local/arm-none-eabi/lib/
crt0.o      ldscripts  libm.a     libssp_nonshared.a   libstdc++.a-gdb.py  libsupc++.la
elf2flt.ld  libc.a     libssp.a   libssp_nonshared.la  libstdc++.la    thumb
fpu         libg.a     libssp.la  libstdc++.a          libsupc++.a
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I link to the libm.a included with arm-none-eabi I get hundreds of unresolved references from that file :\

Comment: You might need to link `libgcc`. Try adding `-lgcc` to your linker flags.

Comment: After adding the arm-none-eabi libm.a math library for the armv7e-m architecture, I got a million other unresolved errors. Adding the -nostartfiles flag fixed the problem, and I was able to use the arm math library.